# Issue printing array list constructed of defined classes

Tags: java, arraylist, system.out

I am attempting to construct a list of rows which contain cells. The classes row and cell have been defined.

I want to construct the array list and then print it.

My Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class findBfs
{
int numWarehouses;
int numCustomers = 4;


ArrayList<Integer[]> warehouses = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

Integer[] warehouse1 = {3,6,8,2};
Integer[] warehouse2 = {6,1,2,5};
Integer[] warehouse3 = {7,8,3,9};

class Cell {

    int cost;
    int shipment;

    public Cell(int x, int y){

        x = cost;
        y = shipment;

    }

    public int getCost(){

        return cost;
    }

    public int getShipment(){

        return shipment;
    }

    public void updateShipment(int newAmount){

        shipment = newAmount;

    }

}

class Row{

    public Row(Integer[] warehouse) {

        ArrayList<Cell> row = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        for(int value: warehouse) {

            row.add(new Cell(value, 0));

        }
    }
}

ArrayList<Row> tableu = new ArrayList<Row>();

public findBfs()
{
   warehouses.add(warehouse1);
   warehouses.add(warehouse2);
   warehouses.add(warehouse3);


    for(Integer[] thisWarehouse : warehouses)
    {
       tableu.add(new Row(thisWarehouse));
    }
}

public void printTableu() {

    for(Row thisRow : tableu) {
       System.out.println(thisRow);
    }
}
}
```

Currently with the code I have the following gets printed:

```
findBfs$Row@25ca623f
findBfs$Row@9f8297b
findBfs$Row@36b4f5a
```

What has happened? :(

Comment: Check out the `Object#toString()` method.

Comment: I'd say that `toString()` would be the way to go, but you don't have any fields in `Row`, so that would be moot.

Comment: What output you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have declared `row` `ArrayList<Cell>` type as local to the constructor. Declare it in your class context: which is probably you are wanting.
2. override the `toString()` method and provide an implementation in the `Row` class with proper format you want it to see as `String`. You will probably need to override `toString()` method and provide an implementation for the `Cell` class too.
3. For a List of specific element, i prefer to declare the list with the element name as prefix and `list` as suffix: suppose instead of `ArrayList<Cell>row`, declare it as `ArrayList<Cell>cellList`

For example:

```
class Cell {
    // your other code

    @Override
    public void String toString() {
        return "shipment: " + shipment + "; cost: " + cost;
    }
}

class Row{
    ArrayList<Cell> cellList = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    public Row(Integer[] warehouse) {

        for(int value: warehouse) 
            cellList.add(new Cell(value, 0));

    }

  @Override
    public void String toString() {
        return cellList.toString();
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

you are assigning the class variable wrongly, `constructor_local_var <- class_var`: which should be `class_var <-- constructor_local_var`

```
public Cell(int x, int y){

        cost = x;
        shipment = y;

    }
```

Comment: This now prints out the values but all values seem to be 0, the costs are not being printed out.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Row{

    ArrayList<Cell> row = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    public Row(Integer[] warehouse) {

        for(int value: warehouse) {

            row.add(new Cell(value, 0));

        }
    }
}
```

i think doing this and overriding `toSting()` will help

Answer (score 1):

When an object is printed out, it is converted to a `String` first, using the `toString()` method. Since you did not override it, you're getting the default implementation from `Object`, which, as you can see, is pretty useless.

You should just override it, like you override any other method. E.g.:

```
class Cell {
    // snipped

    @Override
    public void String toString() {
        return "Cell [shipment: " + shipment + "; cost: " + cost + "]";
    }
}

class Row {
    // snipped

    @Override
    public void String toString() {
        // row.toString() could be simpllified to row - added for clarity.
        return "Row: " + row.toString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `row` at Row class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `warehouse` or the `row` variable in the `Row` class, depending on what you want to print, and then override the `toString()` method.

Following is an example implementation of the `Row` class for the `warehouse` version.

```
class Row {

    private Integer[] warehouse;

    public Row(Integer[] warehouse) {

        this.warehouse = warehouse;

        ArrayList<Cell> row = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        for (int value : warehouse) {
            row.add(new Cell(value, 0));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.asList(this.warehouse).toString();
    }
}
```